# How can I consistently see the "renderable" version of a views field?

Tags: views, 8, entities

I created a custom views style plugin. I currently use:

```
$value = $view->field[$label_column]->getValue($row);
```

to get the value of the field. However, I was recently informed that this does not work for list fields(like 0=>'yes'=, 1=>'no'). This original line displays 0 and 1 instead of 'yes' and 'no'. This user suggested I use:

```
$items = $view->field[$label_column]->getItems($row);
$value = $view->field[$label_column]->render_item(1, $items[0]);
```

It seems like this solution does not work on standard fields. I also recently found that the original line does not respect field rewrites. Is there a universal way to see the field value after rewrites, while also respecting lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [advancedRender()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21Plugin%21views%21field%21FieldPluginBase.php/function/FieldPluginBase%3A%3AadvancedRender/8.4.x), this is a method in the base class of views fields, which renders an entity field respecting field rewrites and other settings:

```
$value = $field->advancedRender($row);
```